# Connection and cursor still usable outside with block

Tags: python, sqlite, python-db-api

My system:

- Windows 10 x64
- Python version 3.9.4
- SQLite3 module integrated in the standard library

A DB connection and a cursor are both considered resources, so that I can use a `with` clause.

I know that if I open a resource in a `with` block, it will be automatically closed outside it (files work in this way).

If these assumptions are correct, why can I access a connection or a cursor even from outside the `with` block?

Try this:

```
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect('test.db') as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    # some code here....


# Now we are outside with block but I can still use conn and cur
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users 
            (name TEST, surname TEXT) ''')
cur2 = conn.cursor()
```

Comment: "I know that if I open a resource in a `with` block, it will be automatically closed outside it". You are mistaken. Closing a resource is just one thing a context manager's `__exit__` method *could* do; it's not a universal property of a `with` statement or all context managers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context manager does not *close* the connection on exit; it either commits the last transaction (if no exception was raised) or rolls it back. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-use-the-connection-context-manager):

> **Note** The context manager neither implicitly opens a new transaction nor closes the connection. If you need a closing context manager, consider using `contextlib.closing()`.

Related, there is no new scope associated with the `with` statement, so both `conn` and `cur` are still in scope following the statement.

If you *want* the `with` statement to close the connection, do as the documentation suggests:

```
from contextlib import closing


with closing(sqlite3.connect('test.db')) as conn:
    ...
```